# Why printf adds a '+' sign when using both the plus and p flags?

Tags: c, printf, documentation

[Some Linux documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), including a Debian man page, specifies:

> `p`: The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if by %#x or %#lx).
>
> `+`: A  sign (+ or -) should always be placed before a number produced by a signed conversion.  By default, a sign is used only for negative numbers.  A + overrides a space if both are used.

So, with those information, I understand that the `+` flag only produce an effect when used with a signed conversion(`%i` `%d` etc)

But `%p` converts to, if we follow the documentation, a `void *` which is neither of signed or unsigned type. And at best we can say it converts to an `unsigned long` which *is not signed*.

So why when I use `printf("%+p", 1)` it prints `+0x1" ?

Comment: "Conversion specifiers" do not perform a type conversion. They "convert" a value of a certain known type into some sort of output. If you hand printf a different type than expected, it invokes undefined behavior. `%p` doesn't _convert_ the argument to a `void*`, it _expects_ the argument to be a `void*`, or else all bets are off. And yes these functions are brittle crap...

Comment: What documentation are you quoting? That is not from the C standard. Always cite things you quote.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm afraid I don't see why. If I do `printf("%+#x", 1);` or `printf("%+#lx", 1);`
It prints `0x1` and still not `+0x1`

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, I used the command `man 3 printf` on my debian machine, you're right it's not exactly from the C documentation

Comment: If you build with Clang, it will [give you a helpful warning](https://godbolt.org/z/6x6xb6Y4e). The `+` modifier can't really be used with `%p`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, that makes a lot more sense now ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It adds a “+” because the author(s) of the code either did not think or did not care about the case of somebody putting a `+` flag in `p` conversion, and the code they wrote happened to flow through path where a “+” is added.

Essentially, they wrote something along the lines of:

- If the type is not unsigned and `+` is flagged, then print a sign.

instead of:

- If the type is signed and `+` is flagged, then print a sign.

It is not intentional and has no significance.